# Find the set of complex numbers such that $Arg(\frac{z}{z-2}) = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been stumped by the following question:

Find the set of complex numbers $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $$\operatorname{arg}\left(\frac{z}{z-2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

I think that complex numbers, $z = x + iy$, with principal argument $\frac{\pi}{4}$, all have the property $x = -y$. I then become a bit lost.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How do you define $\operatorname{Arg}$?

Comment: As pointed out by @José Carlos Santos, $\operatorname{arg}$ is different from $\operatorname{Arg}$. You need to explain which one you are referring to and most importantly mention what did you attempt to do.

Comment: This is a complex mappings question, and I'm really stuck. I am referring to Arg which is in the range -pi < Arg(z) <= pi. 
Generally, arg(z_1*z_2) = arg(z_1) + arg(z_2) but this is not always the case with Arg, so I can't use that property.  
z/(z-2) = exp(i(2*k*pi+pi/4)), k is an integer

Comment: Hint: write $\frac{z}{z-2}=1+\frac2{z-2}$

Answer (score 1):

In general,
for $~w_1, w_2 \in \Bbb{C} ~: ~w_2 \neq 0,$ 
with $~\overline{w_2} = ~$ the complex conjugate of $w_2$, 
you have that 
$\displaystyle \frac{w_1}{w_2} = \frac{w_1 \times \overline{w_2}}{|w_2|^2}.$

This implies that

$\displaystyle ~\text{Arg}\left[\frac{w_1}{w_2}\right] 
~= ~~\text{Arg}\left[w_1 \times \overline{w_2}\right].$

Set $z = x+ iy$.

Then, you must have that

$\displaystyle ~\text{Arg}\left[(x + iy) \times (x - 2 - iy)\right] = \pi/4.$

As something of a shortcut, if you examine

Re$\left[(x + iy) \times (x - 2 - iy)\right]$ and 
Im$\left[(x + iy) \times (x - 2 - iy)\right]$

you must have that :

- The real component equals the imaginary component and
- Both components are positive.

The real component is $(x^2 - 2x + y^2),$ 
while the imaginary component is $-2y$.

So, you can guarantee the 2nd constraint above (i.e. both components positive), based on the 1st constraint, merely by requiring that $y < 0$.

So, the problem reduces to identifying all $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2}$ such that

- $y < 0$.
- $x^2 - 2x + y^2 = -2y.$

**Edit**
Originally, my work had one arithmetic mistake, which I corrected, and one (can't see the forest for the trees) simplification that I totally overlooked.

Once Charlotte left me a comment (following my answer), I proofread my answer and found both flaws.

The second constraint above may be re-expressed as $(x - 1)^2 + (y + 1)^2 = 2.$

Comment: A circular arc is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Thank-you so much for the explanation. The solution I was given is a circle $$(x-1)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 2, y < 0$$ and I just couldn't get to it. 
But now I see how this circle can be obtained. 

I kept getting an ellipse centred at (4,0) with $a = b = 2\sqrt2$

Comment: @Charlotte I have revised my answer, based on your comment.  As I indicate, my original answer had one arithmetic error and one (can't see the forest for the trees) overlooked simplification.